# Python script requires input in command line

Tags: python, input, command-line, command, command-prompt

I'm new to python and I'm attempting to run a script provided to me that requires to input the name of a text file to run. I changed my pathing to include the Python directory and my input in the command line - "python name_of_script.py" - is seemingly working. However, I'm getting the error: "the following arguments are required: --input". This makes sense, as I need this other text file for the program to run, but I don't know how to input it on the command line, as I'm never prompted to enter any input. I tried just adding it to the end of my command prompt line, but to no avail.

Does anybody know how this could be achieved?

Thanks tons

Comment: My guess is `python script.py --input filename.txt`

Comment: Can you post the script - or the beginning of the script at least, the part that does the input processing should be pretty clear

Comment: Thanks Ben, this has helped - at least to get me past one roadblock anyway, lol.

Answer (score 0):

if you pasted the code here that would help but

the answer you are most likely looking for is commandline arguements.

If I were to guess, in the command line the input would look something like:

python name_of_script.py "c:\thefilepath\totheinputfile" {enter}

{enter} being the actually key pressed on the keyboard and not typed in as the word

Hopefully this starts you on the right answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Without reading your code, I guess if

> I tried just adding it to the end of my command prompt line, but to no avail.

it means that you need to make your code aware the command line argument. Unless you do some fancy command line processing, for which you need to **import** *optparse* or *argparse*, try:

import sys

# do something with sys.argv[-1] (ie, the last argument)